# Floating point inaccuracies

Tags: c++, floating-point

While writing a function which will perform some operation with each number in a range I ran into some problems with floating point inaccuracies.  The problem can be seen in the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double start = .99999, end = 1.00001, inc = .000001;
    int steps = (end - start) / inc;

    for(int i = 0; i <= steps; ++i)
    {
        cout << (start + (inc * i)) << endl;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the numbers the above program outputs look like this:

```
0.99999
0.999991
0.999992
0.999993
0.999994
0.999995
0.999996
0.999997
0.999998
0.999999
1
1
1
1
1
1.00001
1.00001
1.00001
1.00001
1.00001
1.00001
```

They only appear to be correct up to the first 1. What is the proper way to solve this problem?

Comment: But there are 20 steps in the range you gave. There is no error here.

Comment: You're right of course; I've changed my question so it should make more sense now.

Comment: What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sample output only *looks* wrong because of how `ostream` rounds by default. You can set `precision` to get some other output.

```
cout.precision(10);
cout << (start + (inc * i)) << endl;
```

Here's what I get now:

```
0.99999
0.999991
0.999992
0.999993
0.999994
0.999995
0.999996
0.999997
0.999998
0.999999
1
1.000001
1.000002
1.000003
1.000004
1.000005
1.000006
1.000007
1.000008
1.000009
1.00001
```

Comment: Of course, if you up the precision enough you'll then discover that binary FP numbers can't store decimal fractions very accurately. ;)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/

Comment: This link now gives a 404.