# Calculate compound interest in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, floating-point

```
//calculate on interest rate
for(rate=0.05; rate <=0.1; rate++)
{

    amount = principal*pow(1+rate, year); 
    
    // output data
    printf("%0.2f $%8.2f\n", rate, amount);  
    
}
```

I'm supposed to show the interest rate from 5 percent to 10 percent for an outer loop. For some reason, it won't show from 0.05 to 0.10 as a result. When I change the numbers from 0.05 to 5 and 0.10 to 10. It works for me.

That gave me a hint that I cannot use decimal places for a loop. How can I fix that? I have to display as decimal places.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For loop with float as counter, increasing by 0.01, does not print expected float values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124040/for-loop-with-float-as-counter-increasing-by-0-01-does-not-print-expected-floa)

Comment: [Floating point inaccuracies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4575643/995714), [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/995714)

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing `rate` by `1` (via `rate++`), but really you want to increment it by `0.01`.  Try this instead:

```
for(rate = 0.05f; rate <= 0.1f; rate += 0.01f)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, I never knew that. Thank you so much :)

Comment: that would not solve the problem in every cases, it might not even work when float is not 32-bit IEEE-754 single precision

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc what are you talking about?  C++ defines `float` as having ~7 digits of precision

Comment: for example if the accumulator result is slightly larger than 0.1 then it'll stop at ~0.09. If exactly 6 loops is expected then floating-point math is not the way to go

Comment: Yeah, perhaps it technically should be `rate <= 0.1f + FLT_EPSILON`, but I think this is close enough (pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

What do you think the ++ will do on a floating number? Plus 0.1, or 0.01, or 0.001? It adds ONE (1) to the number regardless of the type, e.g. int, float, double, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, as others said, you're increasing the variable by 1.0 each loop. If you debug or print `rate` after the loop you'll see that immediately

However even if you change the loop to `for(rate=0.05; rate <=0.1; rate += 0.01)` it will still won't work properly because none of the negative powers of 10 are representable in binary floating-point

You must loop in integer by counting in the second decimal places then divide by 100 while calculating

```
for (rate = 5; rate <= 10; rate++)
{
    amount = principal * pow(1 + rate/100.0, year); 

    printf("%0.2f $%8.2f\n", rate/100.0, amount);
}
```